# Set works not as expected for wx.CheckListBox

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am trying to create two item of `wx.CheckListBox` with different lists of choices.

```py
import wx


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(256, 256))
        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        choices_one = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        choices_two = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']
        check_list_box_one = wx.CheckListBox(self, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, choices=[])
        check_list_box_two = wx.CheckListBox(self, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, choices=[])
        check_list_box_one.Set(choices_one)
        check_list_box_two.Set(choices_two)
        sizer.Add(check_list_box_one)
        sizer.Add(check_list_box_two)
        panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Show()


app = wx.App()
MyFrame(None, -1, 'Test')
app.MainLoop()
```

I expected two `CheckListBox`s with different entry ('a', 'b', 'c') and ('d', 'e', 'f', 'g'). But the second box was shown expanded to four items (as number of items at `choice_two` list) field with values from `choice_one` list.

Comment: Do not give wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL argument to CheckListBox, this are flags for a sizer. The second argument of most (almost all) wxPython controls is the widget ID. Simply pass -1 and it should work.

Comment: Thanks!!! You are right, it is works! Hanks a lot!

Comment: Interestingly, even with the above error, under wxPython 4+ and python3, your code works. You really should consider moving to python3 with wxpython4. At some point python 2.7 and wxpython 2.8 are going to become obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to use WxGlade designer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((276, 297))
        self.check_list_box_1 = wx.CheckListBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, choices=["choice 1", "choice 2", "choice 3"])
        self.check_list_box_2 = wx.CheckListBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, choices=["choice 1", "choice 2", "choice 3"])

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

    def __set_properties(self):
        self.SetTitle("mainFrame")
       

    def __do_layout(self):
        mainSizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(1, 2, 0, 0)
        mainSizer.Add(self.check_list_box_1, 0, 0, 0)
        mainSizer.Add(self.check_list_box_2, 0, 0, 0)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        self.Layout()


# end of class MyFrame

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.frame.Show()
        return True

# end of class MyApp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```